# How to read the results of my simulation after `bsb simulate`?

Tags: bsb-framework

I succesfully ran a simulation using the BSB library with `bsb simulate my_network.hdf5 test_sim`, and I want to read the data of the `soma` device that I configured. The only new file that was produced is `55db4580-eb4b-4fab-91ef-db163484db9a.nio` but I don't know how to read it.

Answer (score 0):

The `.nio` file you found is in the [NIX](https://scicrunch.org/resources/Any/record/nlx_144509-1/SCR_016196/resolver?q=SCR_016196&l=SCR_016196) (Neuroscience Information Exchange) format. The recommended Python library for reading those is [Neo](https://neo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). In Neo's data model your device with name `"soma"` would record analog signals into `block.segments.analogsignals`, or spike trains into `block.segmentm.spiketrains` (depends on what type of data it records). You can see which device produced the recording by checking the `"device"` annotation of the recording:

```py
from neo.io import NixIO

data = NixIO("55db4580-eb4b-4fab-91ef-db163484db9a.nio")
# There will be 1 block, with 1 segment
simulation = data.blocks[0].segments[0]

for analog in simulation.analogsignals:
  if analog.annotations["device"] == "soma":
    print("Your device recorded this:", analog)

for spiketrain in simulation.spiketrains:
  if spiketrain.annotations["device"] == "soma":
    print("Your device recorded this:", spiketrain)
```